# Programmatically generated UIButtons not responsive

Tags: swift, uibutton, target, generated

I'm generating UIButtons dynamically and placing them in a dynamically sized UIImageView. I created the buttons in a loop, then in another loop I set their constraints based upon the available space . It all works, i.e., the buttons and their text show up nicely sorted BUT on clicking them nothing happens. button.isUserinteractionIsEnables = YES.

When logging the buttons in by final loop I they do not have Y,X coordinates. I think my anchors whould take care of that. Or is combining CGRect with anchors always a bad idea?

**EDIT: Fixed**
On button's parentclass init I had to set .isUserInteractionEnabled = true;
If at any point, a view has user interaction disabled, then it will refuse to perform its standard action, which includes not passing the event to any of its subviews

```
import UIKit

class SuggenstionCloud: UIImageView {

    override init(image: UIImage?) {
        super.init(image: image)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    public func setConstraints(
        topAnchor : NSLayoutAnchor<NSLayoutYAxisAnchor>, topConstant: CGFloat,
        bottomAnchor: NSLayoutAnchor<NSLayoutYAxisAnchor>, bottomConstant: CGFloat,
        trailingAnchor: NSLayoutAnchor<NSLayoutXAxisAnchor>, trailingConstant: CGFloat,
        leadingAnchor: NSLayoutAnchor<NSLayoutXAxisAnchor>, leadingConstant: CGFloat)
    {
        self.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        self.contentMode = .scaleToFill
        self.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor, constant: topConstant).isActive = true;
        self.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor, constant: bottomConstant).isActive = true;
        self.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor, constant: trailingConstant).isActive = true;
        self.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo:  leadingAnchor, constant: leadingConstant).isActive = true;
    }

    public func setLabels(weightedTags: [String: Int], selectedTags: [String]) {
        let buttons : [UIButton] = createButtons(weightedTags: weightedTags);
        createLayout(buttons: buttons)
    }

    private func createButton(buttonText: String) -> UIButton {
        let button = UIButton()
        button.setTitle(buttonText, for: .normal)
        button.setTitleColor(.black, for: .normal)
        button.titleLabel?.font = UIFont(name: "Avenir-Light", size: 20.0)
        button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false;
        self.addSubview(button)
        button.frame = CGRect(x:0,y:0,width:button.intrinsicContentSize.width, height: button.intrinsicContentSize.height)
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.onButtonPresed(_:)), for: .touchUpInside);
        return button;
    }

    @objc func onButtonPresed(_ sender: UIButton) {
        // guard let label = sender.titleLabel else {return}
        print("Button : \(sender) poressed")
    }

    private func createButtons(weightedTags: [String: Int]) -> [UIButton] {
        var buttons : [UIButton] = [];
        for tag in weightedTags {
            buttons.append(createButton(buttonText: tag.key))
        }
       return buttons;
    }


    private func createLayout(buttons : [UIButton]) {
        if buttons.count == 0 { return }
        let topPadding : CGFloat = 30;
        let sidePadding : CGFloat = 32;

        let padding : CGFloat = 10;
        let availableHeight : CGFloat = self.frame.height + (-2 * topPadding)
        let availableWidth : CGFloat = self.frame.width + (-2 * sidePadding)

        var i = 0;

        var totalHeight : CGFloat = topPadding
        var rowLength : CGFloat = 0;
        var rowCount : Int = 0;
        var lastButton : UIButton!


        for button in buttons {
            if totalHeight > availableHeight { print("Cloud out of space"); return }
            let buttonWidth = button.intrinsicContentSize.width;
            let buttonHeight = button.intrinsicContentSize.height;

            if rowLength == 0 && rowCount == 0
            {
                print("FirstButtonLabel  \(String(button.titleLabel!.text!))")
                setFirstButtonConstraint(button: button, totalHeight: totalHeight, sidePadding: sidePadding)
                rowLength += buttonWidth + sidePadding + 5; // FIX annoying first row image overlap
            }
            else if rowLength + buttonWidth + padding < availableWidth
            {
                setConstraint(button: button, lastButton: lastButton, totalHeight: totalHeight, padding: padding)
                rowLength += buttonWidth + padding;
            }
            else
            {
                print("Out of space")
                totalHeight += buttonHeight + padding
                rowLength = buttonWidth + sidePadding;
                rowCount += 1;
                setNewRowConstraint(button: button, totalHeight:totalHeight , sidePadding: sidePadding)
            }
            i += 1;
            lastButton = button
            print(button.isUserInteractionEnabled)
            print(button.allTargets)
            print(button)
        }
    }
    private func setFirstButtonConstraint(button: UIButton, totalHeight: CGFloat, sidePadding: CGFloat) {
        button.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.topAnchor, constant: totalHeight).isActive = true;
        button.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.leadingAnchor, constant: sidePadding + 5).isActive = true;
    }
    private func setConstraint(button: UIButton, lastButton: UIButton, totalHeight: CGFloat, padding:CGFloat) {
        button.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: lastButton.trailingAnchor, constant: padding).isActive = true;
        button.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.topAnchor, constant: totalHeight).isActive = true;
    }
    private func setNewRowConstraint(button: UIButton, totalHeight: CGFloat, sidePadding: CGFloat) {
        button.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.leadingAnchor, constant: sidePadding).isActive = true;
        button.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.topAnchor, constant: totalHeight).isActive = true;
    }
}
```

The Print statements provide the following output:

```
true
[AnyHashable(<unFatMobile.SuggenstionCloud: 0x7fb5fae028e0; baseClass = UIImageView; frame = (10 280; 375 317); opaque = NO; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x6000005de920>>)]
<UIButton: 0x7fb5fac2d840; frame = (0 0; 41 40); opaque = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x6000005d0fe0>>
```

I think I might be doing something wrong with the class lifecycle methods.

Comment: *button.isUserinteractionIsEnables = YES*. The print statement reveals the image view is **not**.

Comment: But when I log that, in the loop it says yes. Doesn't that NO in the tagret log refer to the parent View?

Comment: enable it for imageView ??  `self.isUserinteractionIsEnables = true`  ??

Comment: Yes!! I fixed it!

Comment: I had to enable userin interaction in the parentclass. If a View had interaction set to NO , it delegates all input to it's parentclass

Comment: Note that in the OPs question and in all these comments, the property that needs to be set on the parent view is misquoted as `isUserInteractionEnables`. (No doubt a case of copy-paste error propagation.) The name is `isUserInteractionEnabled`. (Daniel got the property name correct in his answer.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see this has already been answered in the comments but a little background.

When the user taps on the screen, it is the top level view that gets the event. If it has isUserInteractionEnabled set to true, then it performs its standard action (each UIView can do something different on a tap.) The base UIView's standard action is to figure out which subview was tapped on as pass the event to that subview. In this way, the tap event goes down the hierarchy of views from most general to most specific.

If at any point, a view has user interaction disabled, then it will refuse to perform its standard action, which includes not passing the event to any of its subviews.

Another way to accidentally make a UIButton not tapeable is to draw it outside its parent view's bounds. Views only pass events to sub-views that were drawn in their bounds.